# Can anyone explain the function of last line in the following code

Tags: python

```
str_1= input("Enter:")

for i in range(len(str_1)+1):
        
        print(str_1[:i])
```

Answer (score 0):

It means get all the characters starting from the **i'th position for every iteration**